# My connection string is not accepting in creating a web form using C#

Tags: c#

`Executenonquerry()` is giving error for everythng i try whether it's about changing `Table` to `[Table]` as my database table which i created in visual studio itself is `Table` plus it's not working in either web forms or desktop forms

```
//getting error of connectivity for everythng i try
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using System.Xml.Linq;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.Sql;    
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace DatabaseProject  
{  
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page  
    {  
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  

        }  

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  

        }  

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            //inserting into the database..  
            SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;server=local;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MRD0100\Documents\dbms.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Name, Id)"+ " Values ('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"')", myconnection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                myconnection.Open();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text;
                //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                myconnection.Close();
            } 
        }  

        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  

        }  

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            //clears the both textboxes..  
            TextBox1.Text="";  
            TextBox2.Text="";      
        }  
    }  
}
```

**EDIT:** Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: "Not working" is terrible explanation of errors you got.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting..?

Comment: "INSERT INTO Table(Name,ID) VALUES(@Name,@ID)" ... Tablename is "Table"? or is this a sample code?

Comment: @RahulSingh error is :A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: @EdiG. yes the tablename is "Table"

Comment: I even tried this code but same error :                     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                myconnection.Open();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text;
                //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

Comment: Unrelated but why are you doing this `da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);`? You should use AddWithValue()

Comment: but even when am not doing it like the second code i typed in comment.. i am getting the same error :/

Comment: problem with your connection string

Comment: select your database in visual studio and goto property window, you can find connection string

Answer (score 1):

because AttachDbFilename is unique to sql express, you should change your conection string to:

```
    @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MRD0100\Documents\dbms.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

(taken from this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/attachdbfilename-option-in-connection-string)

if from some reason you still get an error:

1. open you managment sudio and login
2. the full name for your connection string is the full name of your instance (inside the brackets)
3. replace .\SQLEXPRESS with that value

for instance:

[image: the full name of an instance on a particular machine]

Comment: on adding the connection string given by you, i got another error in the connection string part as "Keyword not supported: 'datasource'."

Comment: sorry.. my bad..i somehow erased the space netween those 2 word.. it should be Data Source

Comment: `AttachDbFileName` can also be used by `LocalDb`, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance-with-specific-data-file/